# SCP file copy and overwrite existing file

Tags: bash, file, scp

I have a Bash script where I'm issuing an SCP command to copy a text file to a remote server. I want subsequent files of the same name to overwrite the existing remote file. However, the copy does not replace the file but generate copies with a time/date stamp.

Code:

```
expect <<EOF
    set timeout -1
    spawn scp stats.txt user@192.168.0.188:/stats.txt
    expect "*word:*"
    send "user\r"
    expect eof
EOF
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Better use ssh keys pair instead of this !

Comment: Nothing in your code does that. If it's happening anyway it's done server-side somehow, and probably nothing you have control over unless you are also the server admin.

Comment: Thx but Keypairs will only help with authentication I think. I don't have any authentication issues.

Comment: Hi Triplee. Thx. I'm the server admin and this is a lab environment. Perhaps using a different SCP server would help?

Comment: ssh key pair permit to not use `expect`. Seems a bazooka to catch a fly

Comment: Gilles: This was just a snippet of my code. Using the SCP from the command line will give the same result. Bottom line: Its not my code or keypairs. I'm leaning towards using an alternate SCP server. Right now its Solarwinds (freeware).

Comment: The issue of refusing to use keypairs and preferring to use `expect` has no bearing on the problem you are asking about, but is frightening and/or amusing.

Comment: A different SSH server also seems like a weird approach to this issue. Figure out if the server you are using is actually doing this before replacing it entirely. My top two hypotheses are (1) it's not actually happening and you are confused; or (2) you have a server-side cron job or something, not actually a bug or configuration problem in the SSH server software itself.

Comment: If I end up with 10 files with time/date stamps there's little room for confusion. Replacing the server is a non-issue but I'll submit a ticket to determine if it's a known issue.

Comment: I should also add that the sending station is a MAC. The server is a Windows 10 laptop running SolarWinds SSH/SCP. Command line SCP (only) from the MAC gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Issue turned out to be a somewhat hidden setting on the Solarwinds Server to allow or disallow overwrite/renaming. Thanks everyone for contributing.